# delphi - how do I make a tick in front of a TMainmenu's item?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I want to place a tick or "x" in front of a `TMainMenu` item when I click on it. Is there any way to do that?

[image]

Comment: Set the `TMenuitem`'s `Checked`property to `true`.

Comment: The exact answer to the question is the first comment here really, answers provide a solution for toggling an item.

Comment: @Sertac, it is not, it says _"I want to place a tick or "x" in front of a TMainMenu item **when I click on it**"_. Well, it doesn't say anything about removing such mark, but I just assumed it's the wanted behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable the menu item's [**AutoCheck**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.TMenuItem.AutoCheck) property. The linked reference describes it as:

> **AutoCheck**
>
> Indicates whether the menu item's checked state toggles automatically
>   when the item is clicked.
>
> When AutoCheck is true, then every time the menu item is clicked, the
>   value of the Checked property toggles automatically before the OnClick
>   event occurs. When AutoCheck is false, the application must explicitly
>   set the value of the Checked property (for example, in an OnClick
>   event handler).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the menu item is named `mnuSetting`, just write this in its `OnClick` handler:

```
procedure TForm1.mnuSettingClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mnuSetting.Checked := not mnuSetting.Checked;
end;
```